# How to control file size/no. files for each result of pagination in python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pagination, iteration, aws-cloud9

I am working in AWS cloud9 to download objects from an S3 bucket, concatenate and compress them, and upload back to S3.

I am currently using paginator to limit the number of files per page, but want to start the process again once the limit is reached to iterate through all the objects in the S3 location (eg. 100 objects in my bucket, download and process 10, upload back to S3, then repeat with the next 10 and the next 10 etc until all 100 objects have been processed and uploaded).

My current code just processes and uploads the first 10 files in the S3 location then stops. How do I put this process in a loop to achieve the above?

```
import boto3
import os
from datetime import datetime
import shutil
import gzip

# create the client object
client = boto3.client('s3')

session = boto3.Session()
s3r = session.resource('s3')

# bucket and folder urls
bucket= 'my-bucket'
Prefix = 'env/path'
separator = '/'
env, path = Prefix.split(separator)
dest_folder = 'dest'

# get date info for file name
curr_dt = datetime.now()
dt_str = curr_dt.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S%f')[:-3]

# initiate list of files to process
files_to_concat = []

paginator = client.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
operation_parameters = {'Bucket': bucket,
                        'Prefix': Prefix + separator}
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(**operation_parameters, PaginationConfig={'MaxItems': 10})
for page in page_iterator:
    print(page['Contents'])

    for obj in page['Contents']:
        key = obj['Key']
        print(key)
        tmp_dir =  '/tmp/' + key[key.rindex('/')+1:] 
        if not os.path.exists('/tmp/'):
            os.makedirs(tmp_dir)
        elif not key.endswith('/'): #filters for files only
            client.download_file(bucket, key, tmp_dir)
            files_to_concat.append(tmp_dir)
            print('Download successful')
        else:
            print('Cannot download a folder')
    
    #concatenate the files
    try:
        with open('/tmp/' + dt_str + '_' + path, 'wt') as outfile:
            for f in files_to_concat:
                with open(f, encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as infile:
                    outfile.write(infile.read())
        print('Successful concatenation of objects')
        
        # gzip the concatenated file
        try:
            with open('/tmp/' + dt_str + '_' + path, 'rb') as gzinfile:
                with gzip.open('/tmp/' + dt_str + '_' + path + '.gz', 'wb') as gzoutfile:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(gzinfile, gzoutfile) 
            print('Successful compression of file')
            #delete original concatenated file
            os.remove('/tmp/' + dt_str + '_' + path) 
    
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print('Compression of object failed')
            raise(e)
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Concatenation of objects failed')
        raise(e)
    
    s3r.meta.client.upload_file('/tmp/' + dt_str + '_' + path + '.gz', bucket, dest_folder + separator + path + separator + dt_str + '_' + path + '.gz')
    print('Upload successful!')
```

Comment: Your code to "concatenate the files" is running after every 'page'. This means that it is probably overwriting the file on subsequent pages, so that the code to Upload will only upload files from the final 'page'. You should reduce the indentation of that section so that it only concatenates after _every_ file has been downloaded. Also, I can't see where `ceid` is defined?

Comment: thanks @JohnRotenstein, I have fixed by changing the `PaginationConfig={'MaxItems': 10})` to `PaginationConfig={'PageSize': 10})` and the reducing the indentation as you suggested, and now I get separate uploaded files according to the page size (10 items). My mistake - all `ceid`s in the code were meant to be `path` - I have changed this now

Comment: Does that mean the program now does what you want? Or do you want it to only upload a _single_ file?